# Time of Day Notes for Internal Scenes

Tags: formatting, scriptwriting

In a script or screenplay, is it necessary (or correct at all) to include time-of-day tags for internal scenes in which exterior lighting does not feature at all (for example, in a maintenance duct or elevator, or down a mineshaft)?

Further, what is the standard in situations where time-of-day are not merely irrelevant but illogical - for example, when in a spaceship orbiting the sun?

Answer (score 2):

As the first two Google results explain (http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Screenplay_slug_line and http://www.storysense.com/format/headings.htm), time of day will only be used where it makes sense.